# Inherit height from one div to another

Tags: html, css

I want to inherit the height from div content to div information, its not working, heres my code.
Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maximusperson/pssh3jzg/
I would like the red to be the same height as the blue.
HTML:

```
<div class="content">
   <div class="information"><p>Welcome to website,<br>Created by me</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100 % ;
    left: 0;
    width: 100 % ;
    height: 50 % ;
    background: white;
    align-self: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}

.information {
    height: inherit;
    font-size: 24 px;
    font-family: serif;
    font-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Do you ask that the class content must have the height from some other div??

Comment: For class information to have the same height as class content

Comment: Can you please provide any fiddle that you have tried for this??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/maximusperson/pssh3jzg/ , i would like the red to be the same height as the blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide `height` to any div (here, it is `div.content`) in Percent, it is always in relation to parent of that div, and again, I believe parent of `content` div doesn't have any height given at all.

So giving `height:inherit` on `div.information` won't work as you'd expect, i.e. class `information` to have same height as class `content`, instead `div.information`, as given `height: inherit`, will have `50%` height of `div.content`.

[image: height:inherit]

But if you provide `div.content` height in fixed units (Percent is relative unit) like in Pixels, your `div.information` will have exact same height as `div.content` (inherit, so to speak).

[image: height:50px]

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0sxu8u50/).

Comment: Thank you, now i understand :D

Answer (score 1):

Just check it out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pssh3jzg/1/)

Some changes i have made in the code is

```
.information {height: 100%;position: relative;top: 0;}
.information p{margin: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine,

you say to  `.information` that the height is inherit, so  `.information`
will take the `50%` regarding to parent,

if you want the same `height` you must set `100%` to `.information`